# Trouble deleting duplicate records using partition and rank() in sql server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I am trying to identify duplicate records and then delete one of the duplicate record using PARTITION and RANK() n SQL Server 2008. I condition to delete duplicate record is that it should not be referenced in another table.

I have a Language table that has some duplicate languages. Employee table has employees and mapping to language. I have to delete one of the duplicate records if that Language id is not being mapped in Employee table.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_LANGUAGE (LANGUAGEID INT, LANGUAGENAME VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE MY_EMPLOYEE (EMPID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), LANGUAGEID INT)

INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(1, 'ENGLISH')
INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(2, 'FRENCH')
INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(3, 'ITALIAN')
INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(4, 'GERMAN')
INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(5, 'ITALIAN')
INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(6, 'GERMAN')
INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(7, 'SPANISH')

INSERT INTO MY_EMPLOYEE VALUES (10, 'GLEN', 1)
INSERT INTO MY_EMPLOYEE VALUES (20, 'PETER', 2)
INSERT INTO MY_EMPLOYEE VALUES (30, 'MARIA', 3)
```

If you see, I have two languages that are duplicate and one of them is being used by an employee. I want to delete language ids  4 and 5.

```
LANGUAGENAME    LANGUAGEID  EMPNAME
GERMAN          4   
GERMAN          6   
ITALIAN             3               MARIA   
ITALIAN             5
```

I have tried to create a select statement to return what I want to delete:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  L.LANGUAGENAME,  L.LANGUAGEID, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY L.LANGUAGENAME ORDER BY L.LANGUAGEID) AS RANKING
FROM MY_LANGUAGE L
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT LANGUAGENAME, COUNT(*) AS DUPECOUNT
    FROM MY_LANGUAGE
    GROUP BY LANGUAGENAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) LC ON L.LANGUAGENAME = LC.LANGUAGENAME
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MY_EMPLOYEE WHERE MY_EMPLOYEE.LANGUAGEID = L.LANGUAGEID))  
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RANKING = 1
```

This return the following

```
LANGUAGENAME    LANGUAGEID  RANKING
GERMAN              4           1
ITALIAN         5           1
```

When I try to delete I get an error:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  L.LANGUAGENAME,  L.LANGUAGEID, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY L.LANGUAGENAME ORDER BY L.LANGUAGEID) AS RANKING
FROM MY_LANGUAGE L
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT LANGUAGENAME, COUNT(*) AS DUPECOUNT
    FROM MY_LANGUAGE
    GROUP BY LANGUAGENAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) LC ON L.LANGUAGENAME = LC.LANGUAGENAME
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MY_EMPLOYEE WHERE MY_EMPLOYEE.LANGUAGEID = L.LANGUAGEID))  
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RANKING = 1
```

Error that I get is:

> Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   View or function 'CTE' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Any ideas how to fix this or may be it can be simplified. Thanks to @Szymon for showing a temp table solution but I am hoping to get a solution without temp tables (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

```
DELETE ll
FROM MY_LANGUAGE ll
JOIN (SELECT L.LANGUAGENAME,
       L.LANGUAGEID,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY L.LANGUAGENAME, e.EMPID
                        ORDER BY L.LANGUAGEID ASC) rnk,
       COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY L.LANGUAGENAME) cnt,
       e.EMPID
      FROM MY_LANGUAGE l
      LEFT JOIN MY_EMPLOYEE e ON e.LANGUAGEID = l.LANGUAGEID)  a 
    ON ll.LANGUAGEID = a.LANGUAGEID
AND a.rnk = 1
AND a.cnt > 1
and a.EMPID IS NULL
```

Result:

```
| LANGUAGEID | LANGUAGENAME |
|------------|--------------|
|          1 |      ENGLISH |
|          2 |       FRENCH |
|          3 |      ITALIAN |
|          6 |       GERMAN |
|          7 |      SPANISH |
```

Comment: At first, I thought this is working great but it seems that the inner query (join query) will get all duplicates plus the languages that are not yet referenced by an employee. Add this additional language: `INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(7, 'SPANISH')`

Comment: Wonderful! It works now like a charm and this is one of the query that will make lot of people happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT t.LANGUAGEID, LANGUAGENAME, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY T.LANGUAGENAME ORDER BY T.LANGUAGEID) AS RANKING
FROM MY_LANGUAGE T 
WHERE T.LANGUAGEID  IN (
                        SELECT  L.LANGUAGEID 
                        FROM MY_LANGUAGE L LEFT JOIN MY_EMPLOYEE E
                        ON L.LANGUAGEID = E.LANGUAGEID
                        WHERE E.LANGUAGEID IS NULL)
) 
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RANKING = 1 AND (CTE.LANGUAGENAME IN (SELECT LANGUAGENAME 
                                        FROM MY_LANGUAGE 
                                        GROUP BY LANGUAGENAME
                                        HAVING COUNT(LANGUAGENAME) > 1))
```

Comment: Same result as @Justine, it seems that the inner query gets all duplicates plus the languages that are not yet referenced by an employee. Add this additional language: INSERT INTO MY_LANGUAGE VALUES(7, 'SPANISH')

Answer (score 0):

You can get the records from your CTE query into a temporary table and then delete based on that table.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  L.LANGUAGENAME,  L.LANGUAGEID, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY L.LANGUAGENAME ORDER BY L.LANGUAGEID) AS RANKING
FROM MY_LANGUAGE L
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT LANGUAGENAME, COUNT(*) AS DUPECOUNT
    FROM MY_LANGUAGE
    GROUP BY LANGUAGENAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) LC ON L.LANGUAGENAME = LC.LANGUAGENAME
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MY_EMPLOYEE WHERE MY_EMPLOYEE.LANGUAGEID = L.LANGUAGEID))  
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM CTE WHERE RANKING = 1
```

And then use records from `#temp` to delete from the original table.

Comment: Actually I was not looking for the temp table solution although I didn't mention in my question. But this is another way of fixing it but not sure what is performance hit?

Comment: Performance hit will depend on the number of records you're trying to delete as they will have to be stored in a temporary table. In practice though, this information will have to be extracted for deletion anyway.